# Recursive random password generator

Tags: java, recursion, random, passwords, int

I am attempting to write a recursive password generating program in java, but instead of returning one randomly generated password, the console spits out every combination of passwords and just keeps going.

*Also, I'm required to have at least one capital letter in the password, which is why I am randomly generating either one or zero.

**Question**: How can I make this recursive method only print out ONE randomly generated password of `randomSize` length? How can I make the char upper case depending on whether or not `randomCapital` is 1?

**CODE:**

```
public class PasswordGenerator{

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      Random rand = new Random();
      int randomSize = rand.nextInt((13) + 8);

      generatePassword("", 0, randomSize);

  }


  public static char[]chars = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m',
    'n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','0','1','2','3','4','5',
    '6','7','8','9','!','@','$','%','^','&'};

  public static void generatePassword(String password, int position, int size)
  {
      Random rand = new Random();
      int randomCapital = rand.nextInt(1);

      if(position < size && randomCapital == 0)
      {
          for(char ch: chars)
          {
              generatePassword(password + ch, position + 1, size);
          }
          if(position < size && randomCapital == 1)
          {
             for(char ch: chars)
             {
                //how can I make this char capital if randomCapital is 1?
                generatePassword(password + ch, position + 1, size);
             }
         }          
      }
      else
          System.out.println(password);
   }
}
```

Comment: [`rand.nextInt(1)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) returns `0` with a 100% probability, because it "returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)".

Comment: @MickMnemonic, oh whoops haha. I always get that messed up. What about the output of my code? All I get is something like this: aaaaaaaaaa9woi
aaaaaaaaaa9woj
aaaaaaaaaa9wok
aaaaaaaaaa9wol
aaaaaaaaaa9wom........How can I make it return only one password?

Comment: Just to note that `Random` is not secure - use this code for exercise purposes only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're generating every combination of passwords because you're going through every value in your char array at each level of the recursive stack instead of picking a random value for the array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomSize = rand.nextInt((13) + 8);

    String password = generatePassword(rand, "", 0, randomSize);
    System.out.println(password);
}


public static char[]chars = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m',
    'n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','0','1','2','3','4','5',
    '6','7','8','9','!','@','$','%','^','&'};

//I think it makes more sense returning the generated string and passing along the random number generator instead of recreating it at each recursive call
public static String generatePassword(Random rand, String password, int position, int size)
{
    boolean isLowerCase = rand.nextBoolean();
    int randomChar = rand.nextInt(chars.length);
    char c = chars[randomChar];
    if(position == size) //base case
        return pasword;
    if(isLowerCase)
    {
        generatePassword(rand, password + chars[randomChar], position + 1, size);
    }
    else //its either upper or lower case
    {
        generatePassword(rand, password + Char.toUpperCase(c), position + 1, size);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use `boolean randomCapital = rand.nextBoolean()` instead, because `nextInt(1)` always returns `0`. Similarly, `rand.nextInt(chars.length-1)` never selects the last index of `chars`.

Comment: Yea, that's a better option